# Not able to connect MS SQL server 2008 with java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, connection

I tried to connect java with My MS SQL express, I downloaded the sqljdbc4.jar also

When I don't bother with the CLASSPATH and all and I try to execute my program( even with sqljdbc in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib

I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at Connect.getConnection(Connect.java:24)
    at Connect.displayDbProperties(Connect.java:42)
    at Connect.main(Connect.java:78)
```

Error Trace in getConnection() : com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
Error: No active Connection

But If I try and set the CLASSPATH variable to point to sqljdbc4.jar then ClassNotHoundExcepetion is occurring with identifying my classname.

Need immediate help. kindly respond.

I use Command line mode of invoking it, I tried setting the classpath in the system variables dialog box of windows 7. and when I do that or use set CLASSPATH="C:\temp\sqljdbc4.jar" the jre fails to recogonize the main class of my program and throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Connect
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Connect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Could not find the main class: Connect.  Program will exit.

So I am at a loss here.

Comment: i think the jar file has to be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext and not just in lib.

Comment: Did that too.. but to no avail ! :(

Comment: are you sure you are using that instance of java to run the application and not another one? if not you'll just have to add the classes to the classpath in another way.

Comment: I am pretty sure That I am using the 32 bit version only to run the program and I 've set my home and path var to point to that only

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occur because classloader has not found driver jar, how you start your program? 
Have you put `-cp` or `-classpath` if it command line ? Or add to lib folder if web application ?

Comment: I have posted the mishaps that happen when I try other methods in the the question itself for the sake of lack of space. Kindly go through it and respond

Comment: Try to look to the instruction below from Sai Ye Yan, BUT, you do not understand me you can put jar not to the SYSTEM class path just to CLASSPATH to your app like, java -cp <ms libs > -jar <your jar>

Comment: Try to read all console options http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: Would be really helpful if u could spell out the whole command, as I am newbie and don't understand a lot about java. But when I try setting the classpath with "java -cp sqljdbc4.jar connect" it throws me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Connect" ..so futher light on it would be great !

Comment: What is the name of your program jar fie ? What is the name of class that contains main (String [] args) method ? After this information I can provide you sart line

Comment: "D:\>java -cp sqljdbc4.jar;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin\java.exe"
; Connect" When I tried this it still throws me the classnotfound exception for the com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
 and the sqljdbc4.jar is locatated in the working directory

Comment: Mine is a standalone java program named Connect.java and its located in D: , and the JDBC driver is sqljdbc4.jar which I have in the local directory. and have set my JAVA_HOME to point to jdk and path to bin, I work on window 7 enterprise edition

Comment: OK, compile your Coonect.java to the class file, if Coonaect class contains main method to do next steps, create lib folder if directory with Connect.class file, copy to the lib folder all jars related to the MS SQL driver,  - start cmd , go to the directory with class file,  type in cmd next line java -classpath "./lib" Connect and tell us what is happen

Comment: java -classpath "./lib/*" Connect

Answer (score 0):

You should set the classpath to include the sqljdbc4.jar file. See details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx).

Comment: The problem is when I set the classpath to point to the sqljdbc.jar The JVM is failing to recognize the Main method and is throwing a ClassNotFoundException on my class 'Connect' itself :(